# Atribuir uma vez o evento do controle ao método de evento

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, eventos

Estou fazendo uma sequência de telas no formulário, tenho uma tela principal que carrega outras telas, a tela principal é o `Form1`, e as subtelas serão as que vou adicionar na tela principal através do `button`, mas quando eu clico varias vezes no `button` e começo a escrever no `TextBox`, percebo que há uma queda de desempenho.

Descobri que quando atribuo o evento `TextChanged` do `TextBox` que está na tela principal para o método `TextBox_TextChanged()` do `FormDefault` e ao digitar uma certa quantidade de vezes no `TextBox`, o método `TextBox_TextChanged()` é chamado quantas vezes eu cliquei no `button` anteriormente.

Exemplo, eu cliquei 10 vezes no `button` para carregar o `FormDefault` no `Form1` e inseri o evento do `TextBox` no `TextBox_TextChanged()`, na proxima vez, quando eu escrever algo no `TextBox` o método `TextBox_TextChanged()` vai ser chamado 10 vezes. Entende?

Imagine se esse método faz uma consulta de dados enorme. Isso vai ficar extremamente lento.

```
public class Principal : Form
{
    public Principal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormDefault cd = new FormDefault();
        this.textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(cd.TextBox_TextChanged); // aqui esta o problema
        cd.TopLevel = false;
        cd.Visible = true;
        this.Controls.Clear();
        this.Controls.Add(cd);            
    }

    public class FormDefault : Form
    {
        public FormDefault()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender , EventArgs e)
        {
            // se apertar no button duas vezes, esse método será repetido duas vezes
        }
```

Como faço para atribuir somente uma vez o evento `TextChanged` do `TextBox` ao método `TextBox_TextChanged()` quando eu apertar varias vezes o `button`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De fato isto não faz sentido, se você coloca para executar algo dentro de um método que é chamado várias vezes ele executará várias vezes. Você tem que colocar isto em um método que será executado apenas uma vez. Qual seria este método? Parece que é o construtor, certo? Então coloque no `Principal()`.

Provavelmente não dará problema neste caso específico porque no momento que este formulário encerra provavelmente a aplicação encerra junto, mas daria em outros casos, então em algum momento o correto é desligar este evento, isto poderia ser em um finalizador desta classe, mas isto é outro assunto.

Eu já vi muito código vazando memória por causa disto, as pessoas acham que é falha do GC ou algo assim, mas é falha do programador que manteve viva uma referência para um objeto que não está sendo usado mais.

Comment: Compreendo, vou repensar o código

Answer (score 1):

O seu código está causando o problema, pois adiciona um evento novo (new) a cada clique do botão!

A cada clique no **Button1** você adiciona o evento para o **TextBox**, o ideal seria atribuir o evento apenas uma vez como citado acima pelo Maniero no **Construtor**.

Você também pode remover o evento anterior e atribuir o (novo) evento, para isso basta altere o sinal de **+=** para **-=**

Exemplo

```
//Remove o evento
this.textBox1.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged; 
//Adiciona um (novo) evento
//this.textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(cd.TextBox_TextChanged); 
//Adiciona o evento existente (não cria um novo "link")
this.textBox1.TextChanged += cd.TextBox_TextChanged;
```

Você também pode ver todos Eventos associados

```
foreach(Delegate d in TextBox_TextChanged.GetInvocationList())
{
    this.textBox1.TextChanged -= (TextBox_TextChanged)d;
}
```